# How to improve request time to a WCF Service from Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, performance

I have a Silverlight project in a solution of Silverlight Application.  I also have a WCF service hosted in the same solution which exposes some method to the Silverlight app.

When I make a call to the service method from Silverlight it takes 4 seconds to reach the service method.

Why is it so, and how can I improve this?

I have logged time in an object list. I add `DateTime.Now` object to collection at each step, then I calculate reach time of each step. And I am making the call through Service proxy.

Comment: Is this in a debugging situation, or after actually deploying it to a website?

Comment: @HiTechMagic its in debugging situation i.e. at the development end.

Comment: a lot is unclear in your question. How are you measuring that. Is it always 4 sec or just first time. Maybe it executes 4 sec? Are you testing locally? is VisualStudio used for hosting ? etc. provide more info.

Comment: I agree with Valentin do you call your service only once, or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all of your webservices call taking 4 seconds? The first one can be longer because the application is starting, but afterwards, the latency should be limited by the logic of your webservice.

Could you use fiddler, firebug or IE Dev tools to better monitor your service calls?

Comment: service call is at the middle of application flow.

Comment: it's the middle of the Silverlight application flow. Your webservice is on a server. If no other webservices calls were made prior to the one you are monitoring, and after web application recycling, the web application (on the server) has to be restarted. To check this, perform your service call a second time, after the first response. If the second call take as much time as the first, your webservice logic should be the culprit. (I suppose here that the root cause is not a slow network or the amount of data transfered by your webservice.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you are debugging (which you say you are) there is a massive overhead as DLLs are loaded for the service to run. *Open your output window and see how busy your Dev Studio is while starting up the service!*

**The debug environment is not a good indicator of actual performance.**

1. Refresh your Silverlight app page after running the service once. This will mean Dev studio already has the service DLLs loaded.
2. Try running your app installed under local IIS to get a better idea of how it will perform, however the only way you will see the real speed issues is to run it from your live site and test the speed there.